# Handling Map of Maps in Java

Tags: java, dictionary

In the following code,

```
Map<String,Map<String,Integer>> one_index_1 = new HashMap<String,Map<String,Integer>>();
Map<String,Integer> term_index_1 = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
    term_index_1.put("B", 1);
    term_index_1.put("C", 1);
    term_index_1.put("D", 1);
    term_index_1.put("E", 1);
    one_index_1.put("A", term_index_1);
    term_index_1.clear();
    term_index_1.put("A", 1);
    term_index_1.put("C", 0);
    term_index_1.put("D", 1);
    term_index_1.put("E", 1);
    one_index_1.put("B", term_index_1);

    System.out.println("One index for A: " + one_index_1.get("A"));
    System.out.println("One index for B: " + one_index_1.get("B"));
```

I am getting output as follows:

```
One index for A: {A=1, C=0, D=1, E=1}
One index for B: {A=1, C=0, D=1, E=1}
```

where the index for A is getting modified while inserting value for B. Without using another map variable, can I somehow retain the values for the map to get an output like:

```
One index for A: {B=1, C=1, D=1, E=1}
One index for B: {A=1, C=0, D=1, E=1}
```

Comment: You're changing the object that's referenced by two other objects, modifying it will affect them both. I think you should have two different maps for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use different maps for each key, otherwise you're editing the exact same map on both keys, and clearly if you modify one the changes will be reflected on the other, given that they're the same object. Try this:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> one_index = new HashMap<String, Map<String, Integer>>();

Map<String, Integer> term_index = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
term_index.put("B", 1);
term_index.put("C", 1);
term_index.put("D", 1);
term_index.put("E", 1);
one_index.put("A", term_index);

term_index = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
term_index.put("A", 1);
term_index.put("C", 0);
term_index.put("D", 1);
term_index.put("E", 1);
one_index.put("B", term_index);
```

Comment: Yes, that i know. But as i need to assign such values to lakhs of map variables, i would prefer using a single variable. In that sense, can you tell me whether using lakhs of variables will consume huge amount of memory or not?

Comment: @user3905866 It will consume memory for each map, but if you want them to have separate states, that is the only choice.

Comment: @user3905866 don't worry about the memory, what matters is correctness. You simply can NOT reuse the same map for different sets of values with overlapping keys.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez Now the problem is: You cannot create dynamic variable name for java. The suggested ways are: using array or list or collection of the variable. Again you cannot create array of a map. List creation is simple but, to insert values in list you need a map whose values should be dynamic (So, I am stuck with the same problem once again) and with collection+set implementation, one cannot access values randomly (We need to access values serially using iterator). I am totally stuck here.

Comment: @user3905866 you're making this waaay more complicated than needed. Why do you want to create dynamic variable names now? Simply reuse the same variable and reinstantiate it before filling it again. I updated my answer to show what I mean.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez It was an immense help. Thanks.